# How do I select the right version of the CLR in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clr

At the time of creating the new project, i not able to session entry for previous version of .net framework in the drop drown box it should only .net Framework 4 and hyper link for more framework.Even those i have .net 2.0 ,3.0 and 3.5.

Can anyone suggest me what can be done?

Thanks and Regards
Sameer ahmed.s

Comment: Updated title to what I think OP is actually asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2010 requires full (not just client profile) .NET 3.5 SP1 to be installed to support down version targeting. More details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/framework-net-3-5-sp1-required-for-targeting-lower-frameworks-2-0-3-0-and-3-5-multi-targeting-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Once a project is created you can change the targeted version in the project properties.

Comment: hey Thanks Richard, let me install that post which i will update the status

Answer (score 0):

Some project types won't allow you to select older versions - what is your project type? Can you select the framework version on something like a Console Application?

Also, do you have the SDK versions of 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 installed? Just the runtime is not enough.

Comment: Ya i have 2.0 , 3.0 and 3.5 installed , i have selected web, ASP.NET web application.
I dont know why visual studio 2010 did not recognize the previous version of framework